# Convert Web url to Image

Tags: python-3.x, powerbi

I am trying to take screenshot of an URL but somehow it takes the screenshot of the gateway because of restricted entry. So tried adding ID and password to open the link but it does not for reason, could you help?

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

BASE = 'https://mini.s-shot.ru/1024x0/JPEG/1024/Z100/?' # we can modify size, format, zoom as needed 
url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/'#or whatever link you need
url = urllib.parse.quote_plus(url) #
print(url)
Id="XXXXXX"
import getpass
key = getpass.getpass('Password :: ')
path = 'target1.jpg'
response = requests.get(BASE + url+Id+Password, stream=True)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(path, 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in response:
            file.write(chunk)
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what i did is capturing the Web URL screenshot using python, save it as image and load as database to Power BI by convert Binary to Text and read text following Chris web Blog
https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2019/05/19/storing-large-images-in-power-bi-datasets/

Comment: Anyone with a better Idea please let me know